# Modeling a "quiz" as an async "long running process"

Tags: javascript, button, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

A lot of people model their apps as a long string of callbacks that call the next step in the process. I'm trying to avoid that. I'm working on a "quiz" that pops up within a training site.  I'm using the when/then paradigm to start up everything, and I'm liking how it looks:

```
$.when(
    quiz_getQuizData(courseId),
    quiz_loadDependencies()
).then(function(){
    quiz_prepareData();
    $.when(
        quiz_buildPage(target)
    ).then(function(){
        quiz_initEventHandlers();
        quiz_start();
        [here?]
    });
});
```

It shows clearly that first you get the data and dependencies, then you prepare the data and build the page, then you initialize the event handlers and start the quiz.

What if I expanded further to make "taking the quiz" an async process?   Currently, I have a callback that some function will call when it decides the quiz is done.  But for purposes of showing the entire life-cycle of a quiz in one place, perhaps I should add

```
$.when(
    quiz_getResponses()   /* <-- user takes 20 min to answer some questions*/
).then(function(){
    $.when(
        quiz_submit()
    ).then(function(){
        quiz_finish();
        callback();
    });
});
```

The thing is, quiz_getResponses would really just create a deferred object and then an "I'm done" button somewhere in the code would resolve it, triggering the rest of the when then.

I don't like it because getResponses doesn't really get responses (even renamed, it won't DO anything, really). And also, it would still be somewhat not straightforward to find who is "resolving" the object.  So it doesn't seem like a good pattern.

How then can I model the whole quiz a sequence of async events?  would it just be completely terrible to add the code above to the first code at [here] (I think so, because it would be too nested).

What is a good pattern to handle the idea of

- several async init steps
- long wait while user does stuff
- several async ending steps

**UPDATE**
For posterity, this is how the sequence worked out:

```
$.when(
        quiz_getQuizData(quizOptions['courseId']),/* submit courseId, wait for quiz data (questions, choices) */
        quiz_loadDependencies()                   /* wait for yepnope to load javascript and css dependencies */
    ).then(function(){
        quiz_prepareData();                       /* build object for rendering quiz template                 */ 
        $.when(
            quiz_buildPage(targetSelector)        /* wait for template, render page into target               */
        ).then(function(){
            quiz_initEventHandlers();             /* add handlers to click events                             */
            quiz_start();                         /* do any final preparations, show the quiz                 */ 
            $.when(
                quiz_getResponses()               /* wait for user to answer questions (or time run out)      */
            ).then(function(){
                $.when(
                    quiz_getResults()             /* submit responses, wait for results                       */
                ).then(function(){
                    $.when(
                        quiz_showResults()        /* show results, wait for user to close                     */
                    ).then(function(){
                        var result=quiz_finish(); /* do any final operations, hide and destroy the quiz       */
                        callback(result);         /* notify page that quiz is over, send result               */
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Q promises is by far the best

Comment: @Vinz243 wait what? (Disregarding how old, slow, and soon to be overhauled in v2 Q promises are - how is this related to anything here?)

Comment: Tip: Avoid wrapping with `$.when()` when you have only a single function that returns a promise. Also, you should remove that `callback` thing and instead `return` the promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the pattern is totally fine. Waiting for user input is an asynchronous task, which can - and should - be modeled with a promise.

> The thing is, quiz_getResponses would really just create a deferred object and then an "I'm done" button somewhere in the code would resolve it. I don't like it because getResponses doesn't actually DO anything. And it would still be somewhat not straightforward to find who is "resolving" the object.

Your `quiz_getResponses` function should *create* and *show* the button and *install the click listener* on it (or at least the latter if you want to put the button in your HTML). It might even take care of cleaning up the button after it has been clicked (or the quiz timed out etc).

Indeed, creating a *global* deferred and letting arbitrary click handlers (or really, anything) resolve it is an antipattern. The button code should not be "somewhere", but inside the `quiz_getResponses` function.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I wasn't that far off track. buildPage was supposed to build all html, and initEventHandlers was supposed to wire up handlers for everything clickable.  But following your logic, I think I should make getResponses actually add the handler for the "I'm done" click.  The only thing I don't like about that is that the initEventHandlers will then wire functions to events for everything except that one button, which could be confusing if you go to that function to find who's handling the "I'm done" click.  Pehaps a "comment" there will suffice.

Comment: What other events are you wiring up? I'd say that if they are only for display matters, they should go within `build_page`; if they are about actions in the control flow (aborting the quiz, selecting single responses, whatever) then you should build own promises for them. You could also let `build_page` do all the work, and return an object that contains promises from it.

Comment: I have anything you can click on, and what handles it.  Like
`$('#quiz').on('click', '.single-choice', quiz_singleChoice_Click);` 
It's all just interface stuff except "I'm done" and "quit".  So I suppose I should handle quit in get responses too?
NOTE: they're not in buildPage just because buildPage is async and the handlers need to be wired after. (but of course I could put them in there)

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't know what exactly `build_page` does. Yes, `Quit` sounds like a good candidate for a promise as well.